# Triggering jQuery code attached to a radio button when this button gets checked through jQuery elsewhere

Tags: jquery, radio-button

In some plugin the following code runs when a radio button is manually checked:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    $.fn.wc_variation_form = function() {
    var $form = this;
    $form.on( 'change', '.variations input:radio', function() { 
    // this code runs when radio buttons are checked
    });
});
```

In my own jQuery code, I need to checked the same radio button using `prop('checked', true)`. Problem: doing so fails to trigger the code above. How can I make sure it gets executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the event when you change the property. Events aren't detected when making changes programmatically

```
$(document).on( 'change', '.variations input:radio', function() { 
    // whatever
});

$('button').click(function(){
  $('.variations input:radio[value=foo]')
       // change the property
       .prop('checked', true)
       // now trigger the event
       .change();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to work though. I did: $( '.variations_fieldset input[value="Every 3 months"]' ).prop('checked', true).change();